# vlc-android-sdk:3.0.0 not work sample

Tags: android, vlc-android

if they use version 1.0.6 everything goes right, but we targetSdkVersion 23 receive erroare.
in version sdk v 3.0.0 source code does not work. There is a simple sample, VLC sdk v3?

code from 1.0.6 is work , and from 3.0.0 is not work:

```
mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.player_surface);
    mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();

    mSurfaceFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.player_surface_frame);
    mMediaUrl = getIntent().getExtras().getString("videoUrl");

    try {
        mLibVLC = new LibVLC();
        mLibVLC.setAout(mLibVLC.AOUT_AUDIOTRACK);
        mLibVLC.setVout(mLibVLC.VOUT_ANDROID_SURFACE);
        mLibVLC.setHardwareAcceleration(LibVLC.HW_ACCELERATION_FULL);


        mLibVLC.setSubtitlesEncoding("");
        mLibVLC.setTimeStretching(false);
        mLibVLC.setFrameSkip(true);
        mLibVLC.setChroma("RV16");
        mLibVLC.setVerboseMode(true);
        mLibVLC.setAout(-1);
        mLibVLC.setDeblocking(0);
        mLibVLC.setNetworkCaching(0);



        mLibVLC.init(getApplicationContext());
    } catch (LibVlcException e){
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
    }

    mSurface = mSurfaceHolder.getSurface();

    mLibVLC.attachSurface(mSurface, VideoVLCActivity.this);
    mLibVLC.playMRL(mMediaUrl);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an example, based on SDK 3.0.0, published [here](https://bitbucket.org/edwardcw/libvlc-android-sample)